# Image Upload in LWC - Public Link

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, upload, fileupload

Trying to Upload image file in LWC by using `lightning-file-upload` Below is My Code.

Is there any Way i can get the **Public Link**  once upload got Successfully in LWC?

**HTML**

```
 <lightning-file-upload label="Attach Logo" name="logoUploader"
                                            accept={acceptedFormats} record-id={recordId}
                                            onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}>
                                        </lightning-file-upload>
```

**JS**

```
@api recordId;

get acceptedFormats() {
  return [".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg"];
}

handleUploadFinished(event) {
    // Get the list of uploaded files
    const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
    alert(event.detail.files);
    let uploadedFileNames = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
      uploadedFileNames += uploadedFiles[i].name + ", ";
      alert(uploadedFileNames);
    }
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new ShowToastEvent({
        title: "Success",
        message:
          uploadedFiles.length +
          " Files uploaded Successfully: " +
          uploadedFileNames,
        variant: "success",
      })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Read the `documentId` from the Object and  Pass the value to APEX controller.

```
  @track documentId;
for (let i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
      uploadedFileNames += uploadedFiles[i].name + ", ";
     this.documentId = uploadedFiles[i].documentId;
    }
```

This Below Apex Code will Create the Record in  `ContentDistribution` Object 
**Apex:**

```
ContentVersion cv = [select id from contentversion where contentdocumentid =:documentId];
ContentDistribution cd = new ContentDistribution();
cd.Name = 'Test';
cd.ContentVersionId = cv.id;
cd.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser= true;
cd.PreferencesLinkLatestVersion=true;
cd.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit=false;
cd.PreferencesPasswordRequired=false;
cd.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload= true;
insert cd;
```

Below SOQL will return the `Public URL`

`SELECT DistributionPublicUrl FROM ContentDistribution WHERE ContentDocumentId`